# Extract Foreground from Background by making the background white

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Thanks Your time, I am a newbie in opencv and I want to extract foreground from my image by making the background white. So far, I have been able to convert the image background to black, how can I make it white..??

[Input Image](https://github.com/okoliechykwuka/Images/blob/master/IMG_0028.jpg)  and [Output Image](https://github.com/okoliechykwuka/Images/blob/master/bluegrass14.png)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import cv2
import glob
import os


image_data_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/corn_weed_datasets/bluegrass')
gt_data_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/GT data')
image_out_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/corn_weed_datasets/corn1')

curr_image = 0 


for image_name in sorted(os.listdir(image_data_path)):

    curr_image += 1


    image_path = os.path.join(image_data_path, image_name)

    img = cv2.imread(image_path)



    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    l_b = np.array([23,26,12])
    # the array is the our range of lower blue colors
    u_b = np.array([277,255,277])
    # the array is the our range of upper blue colors
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, l_b, u_b)
    # threshold d hsv image to get only d blue color
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask = mask)

    Image = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    cv.imshow('res',Image)
    k = cv.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    if k ==27:
        break
for bb,file in enumerate (glob.glob(image_data_path)):
    cv2.imwrite('../8470p/corn_weed_datasets/corn1/bluegrass{}.png'.format(bb), Image)
#     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(image_out_path,Image ))


cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV color space
- Do color thresholding on the green colors
- Apply morphology to the thresholded image to remove extraneous white regions and save a mask
- Apply the mask to the input image
- Change black to white
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("green_plant.jpg")

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold using inRange
range1 = (30,0,100)
range2 = (255,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,range1,range2)

# apply morphology closing and opening to mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# make mask 3 channel
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# invert mask
mask_inv = 255 - mask

# create white image for background
white = np.full_like(img, (255,255,255))

# apply mask to input
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# apply inverted mask to white image
white_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(white, mask_inv)

# combine inverted mask with masked image
result = cv2.add(img_masked, mask_inv)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("green_plant_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("green_plant_white_background.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("mask_inv", mask_inv)
cv2.imshow("img_masked", img_masked)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Input masked:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm migrating this snippet to java,  # invert mask
mask_inv = 255 - mask   Can you please explain littlebit this line.

Comment: It simply inverts the b/w so that black becomes white and white becomes black. You need to have both versions to do the blending. One version to mask the input. The other version to mask the white image. Then you add the two results together.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for uniform background. Here is the Java implementation for the same.

matImage - input image matrix

```
        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Core.inRange(matImage, new Scalar(30,0,100), new Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(7,7));

        Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, mask, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, mask, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);

        List<Mat> maskList = new ArrayList();
        maskList.add(mask);
        maskList.add(mask);
        maskList.add(mask);

        Core.merge(maskList, mask);

        Mat mask_inv = new Mat();

        Core.invert(mask_inv, mask);

        Mat background = new Mat(matImage.rows(), matImage.cols(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar.all(1));

        Mat img_masked = new Mat();
        Core.bitwise_and(matImage, mask, img_masked);

        Mat white_masked = new Mat();
        Core.bitwise_and(background, mask_inv, white_masked);

        Mat backgroundSubImage = new Mat();

        Core.add(img_masked, white_masked, backgroundSubImage);
```